# How does BBEdit define "Predefined symbols" when syntax coloring?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, bbedit

The text editor BBEdit offers syntax coloring options for various categories of source code, including plain text, comments, strings, language keywords, etc. One of the categories is "Predefined symbols," which is defined in the BBEdit documentation as

> **Predefined symbols** are terms which are not language keywords, but which are predefined by a language's reference implementation, or which are part of a language's standard library/framework support, or which have other special meaning to developers writing code in that language.

When I edit Python files in BBEdit, I find which symbols get colored with this style to be unpredictable. For example, builtin constants `NotImplemented` or `Ellipsis` do not get colored as Predefined symbols, whereas words like `index` or `count`, which to my knowledge have no inherent special meaning in Python, do.

How is BBEdit deciding which symbols to highlight in this style? Is this viewable somewhere? Better yet, editable?

Answer (score 0):

The Python language model is defined in `/Applications/BBEdit.app/Contents/PlugIns/Language Modules/Python.bblm/Contents/Info.plist`. I compared the symbols in the `BBLMKeywordList` and `BBLMPredefinedNamesList` sections of the document to the list of Python reserved keywords and builtins.

Several Python keywords/builtins do not appear in the syntax coloring list, including `async`, `await`, `__debug__`, `Ellipsis`, `NotImplemented`, and some more obscure stuff. I think these are all Python3 features, and I know `async` and `await` were not added as reserved keywords until v3.7, so perhaps BBEdit's syntax coloring for Python has not been updated in a while to reflect new tokens.

But, of more interest to me, there are also about a hundred items that *do* appear in the syntax coloring lists but are *not* Python keywords or builtins:

- Comparison and membership methods: `__cmp__`, `__contains__`, `__eq__`, `__ge__`, `__gt__`, `__le__`, `__lt__`, `__ne__`
- Iterator methods: `__iter__`, `__next__`
- Sequence methods: `count`, `index` (but not mutable sequence methods e.g. `extend`, `reverse`, `insert`…)
- String methods: `capitalize`, `casefold`, `center`, `count`, `encode`, `endswith`, `expandtabs`, `find`, `format`, `format_map`, `index`, `isalnum`, `isalpha`, `isascii`, `isdecimal`, `isdigit`, `isidentifier`, `islower`, `isnumeric`, `isprintable`, `isspace`, `istitle`, `isupper`, `join`, `ljust`, `lower`, `lstrip`, `maketrans`, `partition`, `replace`, `rfind`, `rindex`, `rjust`, `rpartition`, `rsplit`, `rstrip`, `split`, `splitlines`, `startswith`, `strip`, `swapcase`, `title`, `translate`, `upper`, `zfill` (but not `bytes`, `bytesarray`, or `memoryview` methods)
- Set methods: `add`, `clear`, `copy`, `difference`, `difference_update`, `discard`, `intersection`, `intersection_update`, `isdisjoint`, `issubset`, `issuperset`, `pop`, `remove`, `symmetric_difference`, `symmetric_difference_update`, `union`
- Dict methods: `copy`, `fromkeys`, `get`, `items`, `keys`, `popitem`, `setdefault`, `update`, `values`
- Context manager methods: `__enter__`, `__exit__`
- Numeric modules and types: `Complex`, `decimal`, `Decimal`, `Fraction`, `fractions`, `Integral`, `Number`, `numbers`, `Rational`, `Real` (but not `cmath`, `random`, or `statistics`)
- Module and class attributes: `__bases__`, `__class__`, `__dict__`, `__mro__`, `__qualname__`, `__subclasses__`
- Commonly used convention: `self` (but not `cls`)

An overwhelming majority of these tokens are methods and attributes defined on the [Built-in Types](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library/stdtypes.html) page of the python docs — but as noted above, many other such methods are *not* included (like those for `MutableSequences` or binary sequences such as `bytes`). I don't know the logic by which the particular tokens included were chosen.

There is a README file located at `/Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/BBEdit/Read Me.txt` that describes how to add custom language models to BBEdit, which includes a note

> **Note**: Do not open the BBEdit application package to extract or modify the language modules in there. That way lies madness.

But despite this probably sensible warning, I would nonetheless like to remove all these extra tokens that are not keywords or builtins of the language from getting syntax-colored, so I guess I'm about to find out just *how much* madness lies that way…